# How can I pull more (or ideally, all) of the updates via the PROJ object?

Tags: rest, attask

A search on the PROJ object for updates seems to be capped at 20, even though more updates exist. Here is an example:

> https : //[domain].attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v4.0/proj/search?method=GET&fields=updates:styledMessage&ID=[guid]

Conversely, by searching the NOTE object using topNoteObjCode = PROJ and topObjID = [guid], all of the notes are retrieved.

Anyone know a trick to pull more (or ideally, all) of the updates via the PROJ object?

Regards,
Doug

Answer (score 0):

I am working on something similar at the moment and it does not appear that it is possible to pull any more or less than 20 updates using the project->Updates collection. I suspect that is because this is a collection and you cannot pass arguments in.

For items like this I end up simply passing an array of ID's I'm looking for into the updates object as a "in" search against the refObjCode field. There is an unpublished number of ID's you can pass at a time. I think it is around 130, but I always batch it at 100.

It's a bit of a pain sorting the resulting list of updates back into the list of projects or tasks.

Comment: Thanks Craig. One of my colleagues at AtTask suggested adding $$LIMIT=200 at the end, which I've just tried, but (as I expected) it did not have any effect on the secondary updates object, effectively "limiting" my search of 1 guid to less than 200 results (which is redundant).

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work. The $$LIMIT appears to only affect the primary object. I really wish AtTask would better document their API. The amount of time I spend creating test cases to tease out how the functionality works is ridiculous.

Comment: The $$LIMIT is covered in api documentation in the Limits section. Perhaps something else in that part of the documentation could help you. https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Limits